# Double line for ports config in docker.compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I understand how docker-composer map ports, but what does it mean when a config file map two different port couples, as seen in the following example?

```
web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
```

Config sample was taken from [php7-dockerized](https://github.com/hamptonpaulk/php7-dockerized/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) repo.

Comment: it mappes 2 pairs of ports. 80 to 80, 443 to 443

Answer (score 2):

It means that for your web service, nginx container has port 80 open and can be accessed from the outside world on port 80 and also has port 443 open and can be accessed from the outside on port 443.

Here the mapping is on the same port. But you can have for exemple:

```
web:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

Here the ports are not the same anymore. It means that

- in order to access your service from the outside world, you would have to visit let say localhost:8080 on your machine.
- But for nginx running inside of the container, the port to listen to is port 80, so it would be port 80 that would be inside your nginx.conf file:

  ```
  server {
    listen 80;
    ...
  ```